# How to make index in an vector as a pair of (x,y) coordinates?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

     int i,j;
     vector<int> v(100);   // defined a vector of size 100

     for(i=1;i<=50;i++) {
         v[i]=i;             // storing the values as we do in 1-d array
     }

    for(int i=1;i<=50;i++) {

         cout<<"index="<<i<<" "<<v[i]<<"\n";  // It will give output similar 
                                               //   to 1-d array
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So this is the case of one dimensional vector where index of vector is integer and the value is also integer. The above code is running fine.

But i want to take the index of a vector as pair (i,j) and the value as an integer.

**See the below code for more clarification .**

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

         int i,j;

         vector<pair<int,int>> ve(make_pair(100,100));   
         //defined a vector of size of indices (100,100)

         for(i=1;i<=50;i++) {

               for(j=0;j<=50;j++) {

                  ve[make_pair(i,j)]=2; // Storing value of 2 in all the 
                                        // (i,j) indices
              }
         }

        for(int i=1;i<=50;i++) {

             for(j=0;j<=50;j++) {

                  cout<<ve[make_pair(i,j)]<<" "; 
                  // Output should be 2 in all the possible pairs of (i,j)
             }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But the above code is not working :(.
Please tell me how i can fix this problem.

Comment: You are confusing the element type and the index type. In the first, both are integral types. In the second, you switch the element type to a pair, but the index type remains the same.

Comment: Perhaps you want to stop using this `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` nonsense and learn what each individual standard header does. One or more of them might provide a facility you want. OTOH a vector of vectors may be just what you need (`ve[i][j]` is easier to understand and doesn't look ugly).

Comment: @n.m. i know very well for the headers. So you just focus on answering the question.

Comment: @Deepak In a fixed range, sequential, you better use std::array in a 2D form. Example in my answer below. Not vector and for sure not map.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors, like arrays, work only with integer indexes. For a vector vec, the index **must** be in range `0 <= index < vec.size()`, otherwise it either does not compile (not convertible to `unsigned int`) or the behavior is undefined (out of bounds).

You have written

```
vector<pair<int,int>> ve
```

Which means that you create a vector that contains pairs, not that it is indexed by pairs.

Now, if you want a two dimensional vector, i.e. a matrix, you should check [Boost matrix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm). You can also implement it yourself, but making it general purpose will take some effort. The basic idea is to convert the pair to an single integer value. The simplest implementation is:

```
template <class T>
void init_2d(std::vector<T> &vec, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> coordinates)
{
    vec.resize(coordinates.first * coordinates.second);
}
inline unsigned flatten(std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> coordinates,
            unsigned num_columns)
{
    return coordinates.first * num_columns + coordinates.second;
}

template <class T>
T & get_2d(std::vector<T> & vec, 
       std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> coordinates,
       unsigned num_columns)
{
    return vec.at(flatten(coordinates, num_columns));
}
template <class T>
const T & get_2d(const std::vector<T> & vec, 
         std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> coordinates,
         unsigned num_columns)
{
    return vec.at(flatten(coordinates, num_columns));
}
```

and then use it in your code:

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int> ve;
    auto dimensions  = std::make_pair(100,100);
    init_2d(ve, dimensions);

    for(int i=1;i<=50;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<=50;j++)
         get_2d(ve, {i,j}, dimensions.second) =j; 
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=50;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<=50;j++)
            std::cout << get_2d(ve, {i,j}, dimensions.second) <<" "; 
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, instead of reimplementing existing code, you should prefer to use boost matrix. If you are trying to learn how a matrix can be implemented (which is a very good idea), then go on and try to convert the above functions+vector into a class, and put the `dimensions` pair into that class. Having a class, for a matrix, is better than to use separate functions. It is easier to maintain invariants for a class than for separate functions.

Note: you can use `std::map<std::pair<int, int>>` instead, but it will be more difficult to iterate over it and it will be much slower. If it makes your code clearer, using `std::map` is a good idea, but it is not clear cut whether `std::map<pair<...>>` is easier to work with than with `std::vector` + _2d functions.

Comment: All you need for a 2D vector is one line in C++: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> tdv(100, std::vector<int>(100, 0));`

Comment: @AmitG. both vector of vectors and maps are not exactly a two dimensional array, just like my answer isn't. Except for boost matrix (or self implemented matrix), they are all approximations. Vector of vectors require separate allocations for all arrays (potentially hidden on one line).

Comment: OP asked about 2D vector.

Comment: Sure, with arrays it is trivial, but with vectors there are more subtleties, since you can't do some stuff naturally with vectors. For example, resizing the vectors is problematic. Serializing a vector of vectors is also more complicated than with arrays. Arrays can simply be dumped as a binary  (assuming it is reread by the same architecture).

Comment: I hate bugs, so I'd rather use or write a class that guards against bigger class of bugs. I'd rather use boost matrix, or write my own matrix. It will eliminate all bugs related to vector sizes getting out of sync.

Comment: And, as a bonus, you can write `auto matrix::operator[](std::pair<size_type, size_type>) -> reference;`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `map` instead.

[Operator `[]` for map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/) takes `key_type` as parameter which is a container which means you can use `pair` object as index (called key in map), however [Operator [] for vetor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) takes `size_type` as parameter which is an unsigned integer.

Your code could look like the following:

```
map< pair<int, int>, int > notVector;

for(i=0;i<=50;i++) 
    for(j=0;j<=50;j++)
        notVector[make_pair(i,j)]=2; // Storing value of 2 in all the (i,j) indices


for(i=0;i<=50;i++) 
    for(j=0;j<=50;j++) 
        cout<<notVector[make_pair(i,j)]<<" ";
```

Comment: but can you tell me what is wrong with the vector implementation ?

Comment: Because it is implemented that way, I edited my answer please take a look again @Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple

All you need is **1** (One!) C++ line: ...+ Update: Optional macro (the macro is to answer @eneski comment):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ve(100, std::vector<int>(100, 0)); // Initialize to 0

// Turns [wr(pair)] syntax to [pair.first][pair.second] syntax:
#define wr(pr) (pr).first][(pr).second // Wrapper macro
```

And than use:

```
ve[wr(std::make_pair(i, j))] = 35; // For example  
int val = ve[wr(std::make_pair(i, j))];
// Or:
ve[i][j] = 70; // For example
val = ve[i][j];
```

There is no real need to use the `wr` wrapper macro. Use `ve[i][j]` and if you have somewhere in your code a `std::pair p`, use: `ve[p.first][p.second]` instead of `ve[p]` - Both are the same. Also, it is nonsense to take `(i, j)` and to make_pair *on-the-fly* just to use them again as `[i][j]` indexes. If, despite all, one insists on the syntax, than use the `wr` wrapper macro.

--

**But**, in a case of a fixed sequential range, a 2D std::array is a better choice (& you can add the wrapper macro as well, if you insist):

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    int i = 7, j = 5;

    std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100> ar; // 100 X 100
    ar[0].fill(0); ar.fill(ar[0]); // Initialize to 0

    ar[i][j] = 35; // For example

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question asks for `pair` but I can't see any pair in your answer

Comment: The question says "_**But i want to take the index of a vector as pair (i,j) and the value as an integer**_"  and clarify its usage with `ve[make_pair(i,j)]` . At least this is what I understand. So, I don't think that your answer is relevant.

Comment: @eneski If one insist on the ***very exact syntax***, instead of to understand the problem (i.e. `ve[make_pair(i, j)]` syntax) than: `#define make_pair(i,j) (i)][(j)` and use: `ve[make_pair(i, j)]`. Of course it makes no sense here: OP takes `i, j` and turns them into a `std::pair` on-the-fly just to use `i, j` again as indexes. Alternatively, if one insists about the index-type, I added an update in my answer to answer that as well.

Comment: I'm very wary of suggesting a macro with unbalanced `][`

Comment: @Caleth Than, for you, take the `#define VE(pt) ve[(pt).first][(pt).second]` macro, and use: `VE(std::make_pair(i, j)) = 35; // For example`.

Answer (score 1):

another solution: create your own container by aggregating a standard one.

Extremely simplified example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct xy
{

    std::size_t x, y;
};

constexpr std::size_t linear_extent(xy _)
{
    return _.y * _.x;
}

constexpr std::size_t linear_position(xy _, xy extent)
{
    return _.y * extent.x + _.x;
}

template<class T>
struct vector_2d
{
    vector_2d(xy size, T x = T())
    : extent_(size)
    , storage_(linear_extent(extent_), x)
    {

    }

    T& operator[](xy const& _)
    {
        return storage_[linear_position(_, extent_)];
    }

    T const& operator[](xy const& _) const
    {
        return storage_[linear_position(_, extent_)];
    }

    constexpr auto extent() const { return extent_; }

    xy extent_;
    std::vector<T> storage_;
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vector_2d<T> const& v)
{
    const char* sep = " [";
    os << "[";
    auto extent = v.extent();
    for(auto y = std::size_t(0) ; y < extent.y ; ++y)
    {
        os << sep;
        const char* sep2 = " ";
        for (auto x = size_t(0) ; x < extent.x ; ++x)
        {
            std::cout << sep2 << v[{x, y}];
            sep2 = ", ";
        }
        os << " ]";
        sep = "\n  [";
    }

    os << " ]";

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    auto v = vector_2d<int>({5, 5});
    v[{1, 3}] = 8;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply attempting to access 1d vector content as if it was a 2d vector? Perhaps you could use a helper function to convert 2d index into 1d index, for example:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
size_t convertIndex(size_t row, size_t col)
{
    assert(row < ROWS && col < COLS);
    return row * COLS + col;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v =
    {
        0,1,2,3,4,
        5,6,7,8,9
    };

    std::cout << v[convertIndex<2, 5>(1, 3)];
}
```

[This](https://ideone.com/YlbTdU) outputs `8`